# Issue exposing NestJS server in GKE using HTTPS

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I am running into an issue integrating Google Managed Certificates into a NestJS/Express web app running in GKE. I ran into this trying to expose the web server to the internet, with the ultimate goal to be able to type in "www.mydomain.com" and be able to hit the server. As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way to use GMCs in an Express server to be able to accept HTTPS requests, unless I'm missing something or thinking about this wrong.

I am running into an issue implementing Google Managed Certificates in my NestJS Express server, running inside Google Kubernetes Engine. Specifically, there doesn't seem to be a way to do so. I want to allow Nest to accept HTTPS requests, and this is the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/multiple-servers) on how to do so.

```
const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/private-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/public-certificate.pem'),
};

const server = express();
const app = await NestFactory.create(
  AppModule,
  new ExpressAdapter(server),
);
await app.init();

http.createServer(server).listen(3000);
https.createServer(httpsOptions, server).listen(443);
```

My code is as such, because when I try to mimic the code above but without the `httpsOptions`, it breaks

```
const bootstrap = async () => {
  const appConfig = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = appConfig.get(ConfigService<EnvironmentVariables>);

  const server = express();

  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new ExpressAdapter(server),
  );

  await app.init();

  http.createServer(server).listen(80);
};
bootstrap();
```

Specifically, the docs require certificate and key files that I don't have, since I'm using Google Managed Certificates, which holds the private key file and never reveals it. Although I've been down a massive rabbit hole relating to hosting web apps in GKE, this is the first time I've ever done it, so I don't know if that is the only issue, or even the right way to expose a web server to the internet using a DNS. Here is the rest of the config set up to expose the server using HTTPS, with the ultimate goal to be able to type in "www.mydomain.com" and have it hit the GET endpoint for "/". I use the Pulumi IaC tool, which is essentially Terraform, but in Typescript.

Dockerfile:

```
...
EXPOSE 80
...
```

Deployment:

```
const serverDeployment = new k8s.apps.v1.Deployment(
  "server-deployment",
  {
    metadata: {
      labels: {
        app: "server",
      },
      name: "server-deployment",
      namespace: namespace.id,
    },
    spec: {
      replicas: 1,
      selector: {
        matchLabels: {
          app: "server",
        },
      },
      template: {
        metadata: {
          labels: {
            app: "server",
          },
          namespace: namespace.id,
        },
        spec: {
          serviceAccountName: "k8s-service-account",
          containers: [
            {
              image: "server",
              name: "server",
              ports: [
                {
                  containerPort: 80,
                },
              ],
              env: secrets,
              readinessProbe: {
                httpGet: {
                  path: "/",
                  port: 80,
                },
                initialDelaySeconds: 300,
                periodSeconds: 30,
              },
              livenessProbe: {
                httpGet: {
                  path: "/",
                  port: 80,
                },
                initialDelaySeconds: 300,
                periodSeconds: 30,
              },
              resources: {
                requests: {
                  memory: "0.5Gi",
                  cpu: "0.25",
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  }
);
```

NodePort:

```
const nodePort = new k8s.core.v1.Service("web-nodeport", {
  metadata: {
    name: "web-nodeport",
    namespace: namespace.id,
  },
  spec: {
    selector: {
      app: "server",
    },
    type: "NodePort",
    ports: [
      {
        name: "server-port",
        port: 80,
        targetPort: 80,
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Ingress:

```
const ingress = new k8s.networking.v1.Ingress("web-ingress", {
  metadata: {
    name: "web-ingress",
    annotations: {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name": "static-ip",
      "networking.gke.io/managed-certificates": "managed-cert",
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "gce",
    },
  },
  spec: {
    rules: [
      {
        host: "www.mydomain.com",
        http: {
          paths: [
            {
              path: "/*",
              pathType: "ImplementationSpecific",
              backend: {
                service: {
                  name: "web-nodeport",
                  port: {
                    number: 80,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

I have created the Google Managed Certificate, and it is active:
[Managed Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUMnN.png)

I have created a DNS zone with DNS Authorizations from my certificate, using ExternalDNS to add rules to the zone when the ingress is created. Again, this all works when using HTTP. However, when I try to modify the code following [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb) it fails with `Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established`, I assume because I need to accept HTTPS requests in my server, which I can't seem to do without the certificate/key files. There also seems to be an issue allowing HTTPS requests into the Ingress, as there is no HTTPS Frontend rule created originally.
[Frontend Config of LoadBalancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEZDw.png)

When I try to create one, the certificate does not show up:
[Frontend Config Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOv3U.png)

I have read about a certain FrontendConfig object that may need to accompany my Ingress to allow for HTTPS ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#associating_frontendconfig_with_your_ingress)), but again when I try to set that up, I am not able to use my certificate. Am I missing something here? Is there a good way to integrate Google Managed Certificates with a NestJS Express server and GKE so I can use HTTPS?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).